# WordPress custom permalinks using page children

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a wordpress theme and I would like to have a custom permalink structure. Users will add pages that have custom themes and the pages will be nested. So for example, a user might add a page called "Media" and then add a page called "tutorials" that has the parent of "Media". I would like to be able to use the permalink of "example.com/media/tutorials". IS there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the users be able to modify the pages' "parent" setting? If so, why not set a non-default permalink structure and this should be done automatically.

Comment: Yes they can, I am fairly new to WordPress could you explain in more detail what you mean?